# InterceptorDataWrapper createInterceptor No interceptor data for class

Tags: spring, ejb, websphere

does anybody know why this Problem when deploying an EJB project to websphere 8?

```
 0000001e annotations   E InterceptorDataWrapper createInterceptor No interceptor data for class [ org.springframework.ejb.interceptor.SpringBeanAutowiringInterceptor ]
```

The spring dependencies are visible in the ear and the ejb classloader and are located in the lib folder of the ear module.

EDIT:

This might have to do with a post I recently posted: [deployment of an ejb maven project from eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22837917/deployment-of-an-ejb-maven-project-from-eclipse)

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "beneath the ear classloader"?  Are the JARs in the EAR/lib directory, are they referenced via Class-Path, or something else?  In any case, my best guess is that this is a product defect that should probably be reported to IBM via a PMR.

Comment: Sorry, you are right that was not specific enough. Yes the libraries are located in the lib folder of the ear and in the classpath of the ejb module. This is problem is propably associated to an post a wrote yesterday. I will link it above.